# How to setup Sentry to AWS lambda functions? Many errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, sentry

Trying to setup [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) to a service with lambda functions - AWS.
I have followed the instructions on [serverless-sentry-lib](https://github.com/arabold/serverless-sentry-lib) and it works for local environment but not for prod.

1-Have installed raven and serverless-sentry-lib

```
npm install --save raven
npm install --save serverless-sentry-lib
```

Basically this is what I have in my `serverless.yml`:

```
provider:

  environment:
#    SLS_DEBUG:"*"
    SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
    SENTRY_DSN: "https://xxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxx"



plugins:
  - serverless-delete-loggroups
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-plugin-existing-s3
#  - serverless-sentry
  - serverless-sentry-lib
#  - serverless-plugin-optimize
```

And this is how I send the error:

```
myFunction.ts

import * as Raven from 'raven';
Raven.config('https://xxxxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxxx').install();
```

That code works good in Local but when I try to push to Serverless AWS lambda I get the follow error:

```
Serverless: s3 --> initiate requests ...

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  ... Unable to validate the following destination configurations

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Checking this post and setting `SLS_DEBUG to "*"`:

```
    SLS_DEBUG:"*"
    SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
    SENTRY_DSN: "https://xxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxx"
```

And I still have the same error. It did not disappear.

Does someone have any clue what is going on wit this settings?